# Build containers with Jib only if an artifact has been updated

Tags: gradle, jib

**Context**: I have a monorepo that contains several projects. They are built with Gradle. Currently they are packed as OCI containers using Docker in an additional pipeline step.

**Goal**: I want to use Jib inside Gradle's incremental build to construct containers only for the services that were really updated during the build.

**Problem**: Adding the Jib plugin and running `gradle jib` creates new containers for all the projects where the plugin has been added.

What configuration should I apply so that I can construct just the needed containers. In Maven that should be achievable by binding `jib` to the `package` goal.

Adding `tasks.build.dependsOn tasks.jib` on root project level did not work for me.